# Add new line to a file after matching pattern - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file called 'file.txt' and its contents are as below.

```
 [Jack]
 sv0f3fj3jff0j


 [Tom]
 343767y6y6y5yu
```

I have to add new line just after each names(by reading the user name as input). Can any one please help me ? I have tried using the below steps but didn't succeeded.

```
#!/usr/bin/python36

inv_file = '/root/file.txt'
cn_search = input("\nEnter the name: ")
new_line = input("\nEnter the new line : ")
with open(inv_file) as in_file:
     buf = in_file.readlines()
     print(buf.replace('[').replace(']'))
with open(inv_file, "w") as in_file:
     for line in buf:
         if line.startswith('[') and line.endswith(']'):
            mod_line = line.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
            if mod_line == cn_search:    
               buf  = buf + "\n" + new_ip_ex
               out_file.write(buf)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is correct to read and then rewrite the file, but you're also changing the brackets which is unnecessary. Do it like this:

```
import re

with open(inv_file) as in_file:
    old_contents = in_file.readlines()

with open(inv_file, 'w') as in_file:
    for line in old_contents:
        in_file.write(line)
        if re.search(r'\[.*\]', line):
             in_file.write('YOUR MESSAGE HERE\n')
```